# How to use new version of getresources().getColor?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-color

I am trying to get a color element using `getresources.getColor(resource id)` but android is telling me that it has been deprecated use `getresources.getColor(resource id, theme)`.

How do I tell it what theme to use? I have tried `R.style.AppTheme` but I get an error as this is an int value

```
public class TodoListItemView extends AppCompatTextView {
    public TodoListItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int ds) {
        super(context, attributeSet, ds);
        init();
    }

    public TodoListItemView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public TodoListItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        init();
    }

    private Paint marginPaint;
    private Paint linePaint;
    private int paperColor;
    private float margin;

    private void init() {
        Resources myResources = getResources();
        marginPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        marginPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notepad_margin));
        linePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        linePaint.setColor(myResources.getColor(R.color.notepad_lines));
        paperColor = myResources.getColor(R.color.notepad_paper);
        margin = myResources.getDimension(R.dimen.notepad_margin);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(paperColor);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, getMeasuredHeight(), 0, linePaint);
        canvas.drawLine(0, getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), linePaint);

        canvas.drawLine(margin, 0, margin, getMeasuredHeight(), marginPaint);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(margin, 0);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Use `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);`

Comment: Yes.  This is the recommended way to handle supporting different APIs.

Comment: Using null as the theme clears the error, but the application won't start.

Comment: I've tried using ContextCompat but I keep getting version errors on the sdk

Comment: What is your minSdkVersion?

Comment: @user182162 : make sure u have added support library also.

Comment: I have it set to use ContextCompat.getColor, but the app won't build due to the following Error:(17, 12) error: class, interface, or enum expected. There are 29 of these

Comment: this should be shown in a code comment.  It is not clear at all how to use it, and contextcompat returns an integer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the input.  ContextCompat.getColor worked as far as fixing the errors. The interface, enum errors were due to an extraneous closing bracket.

My only complaint is that now the app does not run.  A message appears on the emulator stating the the app has stopped working. No chance to test the changes.